Smoothing Pump Pressure Spikes with a Helmholtz or Pipe Resonator?
When a roots blower runs, it has some oscillation in the flow rate (and consequently pressure) due to lobe geometry. The pattern occurs $4$ times per rotation, so for a direct drive $1800 \ \text{rpm}$ motor, the oscillation frequency is $120 \ \text{Hz}$.
In my application, I need very constant vacuum pressure ($<1\%$ of the absolute operating pressure), requiring very smooth flow. Adding a very large volume between the pump and the user and dampening would help, but it would be large and expensive to fabricate. The user needs around $1000 \ \text{Pa}$, so the volume required and pressure differential allowed. A mechanical regulator of any sort is impractical. Also, since this is near full vacuum, it makes large vessels very expensive to fabricate.
I am considering the following geometry (hand sketch below). The pump feeds directly into a Helmholtz resonating volume, and the user connects at $90^\circ$ at the standing wave pressure node (the center of the image below). Some assumptions here since it would be in a system with flow, but just looking at the oscillating component. When the velocity in the pipe is the highest back and forth, the pressure change should be the lowest (velocities will not be high enough or long enough to consider Bernoulli). Then, in theory, the user sees constant pressure (ignoring geometry and flow considerations of the user inlet).
Image from Acoustic Resonance Wiki:

I did a rough Helmholtz calculation and came to $6 \ \text{litres}$, which is great from a fabrication standpoint but makes me hesitate since it would not be much more volume than the pipe. Alternatively, I could just use a $3$-meter ($350 \ \text{m s}^{-1}/120 \ \text{Hz}$, where $350 \ \text{m/s}$ is the speed of sound) length of pipe capped at the end.
Are my assumptions correct? Would one of these work better than another? Better ideas? Any similar existing applications that you are aware of? All feedback is appreciated. Thanks!


Is it possible to run TWO identical blowers and connect their drives to be 180 degrees out of phase?  There will likely be some oscillations due to the mechanical connection though.

@MarianoG, I had thought of this too, but yeah difficult to get the timing correct and there is definitely no guarantee the pressure fluctuation from the pump is sinusoidal so there would probably be harmonics. Right now it doesnt look the the risk is worth the reward, but might visit the idea again in the future.
